# Anisotropic Calderon-Zygmund decomposition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for the following version of Calderon-Zygmund decomposition, consider an function $f \in L^1(R^{d+1})$ and cylinders of the form $Q_{R,R^p}$ for some fixed $p \in (0,\infty)$, The cylinders are cubes of radius $R$ in $R^d$ and of height $R^p$ in the time direction.

Question: Can I find a sequence of cubes $\{Q_i\}$ such that Calderon Zygmund decomposition holds and each cube $\{Q_i\}$ has scaling of the form $(r,r^p)$?

Comment: Just a simple remark, without having checked the details. If you subdivide into $k$ parts in $x$ and $h$ parts in $t$ you should get any $p=(\log k)/(\log h)$ with $k,h \geq 2$ integers (the case $k=2, h=4$ gives parabolic cylinders). Is this true?

Comment: When k and h are integers, then the CZ theory works. In other cases, the subdivision will produce cylinders that could go over or stay below the previous generation. So I'm trying to understand how to subdivide in t direction when p isn't an integer or rational number.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use Whitney balls which work well in homogenuous spaces and get somewhat weaker results for every $p$. Maybe they suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't enough for my needs because that result is a bit of an existential one. In the sense, there exists a covering with CZ type properties, but the problem is that i don't know which balls are at which scale nor do i have any effective estimates on their locations.

Comment: That is strange. Don't you have the same problem with dyadic cubes? Usually you don't know at which scale they are selected nor which centers.

Comment: Could you please let me know the reference for homogenous spaces and the theorem you are referring to so that i read it carefully first before replying to your comment.

Comment: I have in mind: P. Auscher "Real harmonic Analysis" (you find it free online https://press.anu.edu.au/publications/real-harmonic-analysis), Theorem 2.3.4. Chapter 2 deals with different coverings with or without the doubling property. Also the habilitation thesis by H. Koch http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koch/public.html is very connected (see lemma 2.24 and proposition 2.2.7 for a CZ decomposition in this setting).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references, please give me a few days to see how helpful this version is and/or do I need more properties for my needs.

Comment: Sure, let me know. I forgot to mention the classical references Coifman-Weis and Christ....but you surely know them.